# Is a police escort in Pakistan assigned to the foreigner automatically or must the foreigner request it?

Tags: safety, pakistan, officials

I have read that a police escort might be needed/required in some areas of Pakistan. E.g. https://www.thebrokebackpacker.com/is-pakistan-safe/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190719035836/https://www.thebrokebackpacker.com/is-pakistan-safe/)):

> you might have to travel with an armed police escort in some places.

Is a police escort in Pakistan assigned to the foreigner automatically or must the foreigner request it? If automatically, how does the law enforcement become aware the foreigner needs a police escort? If not automatically, how does the foreigner request the  police escort?

Comment: You have to advise where you are going for a good answer the way to handle it is different depending where you are going from and to

Comment: @MattDouhan Thanks, landing in Lahore and might go around, exact itinerary TBD. I'm wondering whether I should pay attention to police escort or whether it'll be assigned to me automatically. I believe there is no police escort within Lahore but might be outside it.

Comment: Normally the few times I have needed it it has been assigned automatically, but I cannot speak for Lahore since I haven’t been there yet

Comment: @MattDouhan Interesting, when it has been assigned automatically,  how did the law enforcement become aware you needed a police escort? Did you go through some checkpoints?

Comment: For me in three different ways, arranged by my company when we booked the travel, assigned when I arranged a car in Kharaci, and lastly arranged when passing through a check point

Comment: @MattDouhan Thanks, when arranged by your company when booking the trip, was the police escort compulsory? When assigned when arranging a car in Karachi, did the car rental company take care of finding a police escort?

Comment: It was compulsory yes and when we arranged a car the car company helped to arrange the escort when we told where we were going

Comment: Matt, you might consider summarizing your experiences as an answer. While you may not know about Lahore in specific, the rest of the information is still useful in general for how these escorts can be arranged.